# Using matrix multiplication @ operator in sympy expression

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, matrix-multiplication

If I make a Sympy expression with symbols `a,b,c` as follows

```
import sympy as sm
import numpy as np
a,b,c = sm.symbols("a,b,c")
expr = 4*a + b*a + b*c + a*b*c

f = sm.lambdify((a,b,c), expr)
a_1 = np.random.rand(10,10)
b_1 = np.random.rand(10,10)
c_1 = np.random.rand(10,10)
f(a_1, b_1, c_1)
```

The problem here for me, is that lambdify uses `*` in `numpy` which is just the element-by-element multiplication, but I need the matmul or `@` operator in the above function. Above code is just an example, and in some of my use cases the expression becomes complicated to use. I tried to look for methods to achieve this in Sympy, but `lambdify` does not work with this operator. I was wondering whether a symbol existed which acts like a matrix for multiplication operators in Sympy, where the matrix size specification is not necessary, but I could not find any. It is also important for me that I can use the same function for matrices of different size choice of a, b and c. Any suggestion would be very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The normal usage of arrays with `lambdify` is to evaluate a scalar expression over many values of the symbols in the expression. If you want to use arrays as matrices and have matrix multiplication then your symbols need to be `MatrixSymbol`:

```
In [235]: A = MatrixSymbol('A', 2, 2)

In [236]: B = MatrixSymbol('B', 2, 2)

In [237]: f = lambdify((A, B), A*B)

In [238]: import inspect

In [239]: inspect.getsource(f)
Out[239]: 'def _lambdifygenerated(A, B):\n    return (A).dot(B)\n'

In [240]: print(inspect.getsource(f))
def _lambdifygenerated(A, B):
    return (A).dot(B)

In [241]: a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

In [242]: f(a, a)
Out[242]: 
array([[ 7, 10],
       [15, 22]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This process, unfortunately, is not applicable for my need, as the matrices I normally use have sizes of around 20,000x20,000. So, I don't think defining symbols that way is even possible.

Comment: You can use `MatrixSymbol('A', n, m)`, where `n,m` are integer symbols.  But even that's not necessary, since the `lambdified` code does not specify shapes.  `f(eye(1000),eye(1000))` should run.

Comment: I tried to do this as well, the problem is I no longer can use the `sympy.cos(a)` when a is a symbolic matrix. This does not work with other functions like exp too I think, which makes it difficult to use matrix symbols.